# Guava Futures Wait for Callback

Tags: java, guava, future

I have a list of futures and on completion of each future, I have a callback that should get executed.

I am using Futures.successfulAsList to check if all the futures have completed. However, this doesn't take into account the completion of callback.

Is there a way I can ensure the callback is completed?

Instead of Callback, I could use Futures.transform to wrap into another Future and check for completion of that. However, with this, I don't get access to runtime exception thrown in the wrapped future.

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));

List<ListenableFuture<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  final int x = i * 100;

  ListenableFuture<Object> future = service.submit(new Callable() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
      Thread.sleep(10000 / x);

      return x;
    }
  });

  futures.add(future);

  Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object x) {
      try {Thread.sleep((Integer) x * 10);} catch (Exception e) {}

      System.out.println(x);
    }
  });
}

ListenableFuture<List<Object>> listFuture = Futures
    .successfulAsList(futures);
System.out.println("Waiting...");
System.out.println(listFuture.get());
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: This is a really great question as it seems to me it might be a fairly common use case that is not directly supported by the Guava API.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to block until the callbacks for the N tasks you submit have all completed, you could create a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a `count` of N. Then just call `countDown()` on it when each callback completes (whether it succeeds or fails) and `await()` it at the point you want to block.

Alternatively, you could do something like you did in your answer, but rather than using a `ListenableFutureTask<Void>` and a no-op `Runnable`, just use a `SettableFuture<Void>` instead and call `set(null)` on it on completion.

Comment: I went with the `CountDownLatch` approach. Works nicely and is clean to implement!

Answer (score 1):

How about if you create another future for each callback and make sure that it will be completed inside the callback.

```
// create "callback" future here
futures.add(callbackFuture);

Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
    // do something with callbackFuture
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Object x) {
    try {Thread.sleep((Integer) x * 10);} catch (Exception e) {}

    System.out.println(x);
    // do something with callbackFuture
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the callbackFuture you are referring to?

Comment: Just some future that you can access inside your callback. Nothing special. Doesn't even have to do anything. (I'm not familiar with the guava classes; in java.util.concurrent you would do a "new FutureTask()" with an emtpy runnable and call run() on it inside the callback after which isDone() would return true; Guava surely has something equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou, this works!

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));

List<ListenableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i ++) {
  final int x = i * 100;

  ListenableFuture<Object> future = service.submit(new Callable(){
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
      Thread.sleep(10000 / x);

      return x;
    }
  });

  //Blank runnable to evaluate write completion
  Runnable callback = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do nothing
    }
  };

  final ListenableFutureTask<Void> callbackFuture = ListenableFutureTask.create(callback, null);

  futures.add(callbackFuture);

  Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      try {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
        callbackFuture.run();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object x) {
      try {
        try {Thread.sleep((Integer)x*10);}catch(Exception e){}

        System.out.println(x);
      }
      finally {
        callbackFuture.run();
      }
    }
  });
}

ListenableFuture<List<Void>> listFuture = Futures.successfulAsList(futures);
System.out.println("Waiting...");
System.out.println(listFuture.get());
System.out.println("Done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Realization without sleep:

```
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));

    List<ListenableFuture<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        final int x = i * 100;

        ListenableFuture<Object> future = service.submit(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(10000 / x);

                return x;
            }
        });

        Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object x) {
                try {Thread.sleep((Integer) x * 10);} catch (Exception e) {}

                System.out.println(x);
            }
        });

        /* all Callbacks added in one list (ExecutionList) and executed by order. If not defined 3d argument (Executor)
           then callbacks executed sequentially at task thread.
         */
        final SettableFuture<Object> lastCalledFuture = SettableFuture.create();
        Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                lastCalledFuture.set(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                lastCalledFuture.setException(t);
            }
        });
        futures.add(lastCalledFuture);
    }

    ListenableFuture<List<Object>> listFuture = Futures
            .successfulAsList(futures);
    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    System.out.println(listFuture.get());
    System.out.println("Done");
```